# Get exact installed version from npm package

Tags: fedora, package-management, javascript

How do I find the exact installed version of a package from package.json in an express application in a Fedora distribution?

I could look through package-lock.json but are there an easier way, as it's huge?

I've tried

```
npm list
```

but it's not installed and I don't want to install it if is not necessary.

Any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

For NPM to get a list of package versions you must first 
cd to the folder where your NPM application is.

Then run (from folder where you run your npm apps)

```
npm ls --depth=0
```

If you dont see anything try the command with global setting

```
npm -g ls --depth=0
```

Comment: I do need to install npm on the server then as I get `-bash: npm: command not found`  when running above command. I'm looking for a way to not have to install npm as its and elastic beanstalk that "resets" it self when i rebuild it/scale it.

Answer (score 0):

The following script searches the package.json file in the directory where it is executed for the specified package and prints out its version:

```bsh
# getPackageVersion.sh
# Searches the package.json for a specific package and prints out its version
#
# Usage:
# chmod +x getPackageVersion.sh
# ./getPackageVersion.sh <package_name>

packageName=$1

if [ ! -f ./package.json ]; then
    echo "package.json file not found in current directory."
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$packageName" ]
then
    echo "No package name given."
    exit
fi

packageJsonOutput=$(cat package.json | grep "\"$packageName\": \"*\"")
version=(${packageJsonOutput//:/ })
version=${version[1]//\"/}

if [ "$version" == "" ]
then
    echo "Package not found."
    exit
fi

echo "$version"
```

### Usage

```bsh
chmod +x getPackageVersion.sh
./getPackageVersion.sh <package_name>
```

### Example

```bsh
$ cd ~/sw/your-project/
$ ./getPackageVersion.sh debug
4.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use yarn as package manager, yarn.lock contains the exact version that is resolved during `yarn install` command run.